# Where is AppAnnie getting App Store rankings beyond #200?

Tags: ios, mobile, analytics

Apple's official RSS Feed Generator is limited to 200 results, here's an example: https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=200/xml

How is AppAnnie getting anything beyond that?

Is it possible to get those ranks by using the official iTunes Search API?